# 404 route gets rendered for a split-second

Tags: reactjs

```
<Switch>
  {this.state.journals.length !== 0 &&
    this.state.journals.map((journal) => (
      <Route
        key={journal._id}
        exact
        path={this.getJournalLinks(journal)}
        render={(props) => <Page journal={journal} {...props} />}
      />
    ))}

  <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

`NotFound` route gets rendered for a few seconds before jumping into the `Page` component. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: It is probably the time it takes to render the `map` and render the componen inside, the notFound is there before

Comment: What's the initial state for `journals`?

Comment: empty array, pulling data from db. @palindrom

Comment: So initially your `journals` is empty hence the map does nothing. So all it exist is the 404 page. When you `journals` fills up - then the component re-renders and the `.map` fires up generating more routes. To prevent this would be to either get the `journals` before routing OR drop a `loading` screen if the `journals` is empty.

Comment: ALSO fyi you can simply do `this.state.journals?.map( ... rest of code )` instead of `this.state.journals.length !== 0 && this.state.journals.map(... rest of the code)`. Adding a simple `?` before `.map` will simplify the statement, make it a lot easier to read and will function the same - if `.map` does not exist - it will not function. since `null` dosent have `.map` - even tho `journals` is empty - it will not be ran. The same can be applied to anything - objects, variables, functions, anything

Comment: Thanks, great tip @Lith, it's been solved.